# Drawing lines using a for loop after positioning SVG path

Tags: javascript, canvas, svg, charts, raphael

I am trying to make a line chart using SVG Raphael. This has already been executed using canvas. While drawing the line curves in canvas a moveTo is done to position the first point of the line, and then a for loop applied for consecutive points to draw a line using lineTo. But I have no idea how to apply this in Raphael.
Would it be possible to insert a for loop in the paper.path method? The data are as follows:

```
var x1 = pts[0],
    y1 = pts[1],
    x2 = pts[i]*scaleX,
    y2 = pts[i+1]*scaleY;
```

The code should follow this idea:

```
paper.path("M" + x1 + "," + x2);
//then a for loop
for(var i=2;i<pts.length-1;i+=2){
  paper.path("L" + x2 + "," + y2);
}
```

I know the syntax is completely wrong for the above but thats the basic idea of whats to be done. Is there any way to execute this?

EDIT: The actual code used is as follows which gives the error Object # has no method 'path'

```
var linedataline = [{dataPoints : [{ x: 0,
                                        y: 0
                                    }, {
                                        x: 20,
                                        y: 20
                                    }, {
                                        x: 35,
                                        y: 25
                                    }, {
                                        x: 26,
                                        y: 32
                                    }, {
                                        x: 47,
                                        y: 40
                                    }, {
                                        x: 42,
                                        y: 47
                                    }, {
                                        x: 65,
                                        y: 68
                                    }, {
                                        x: 85,
                                        y: 88
                                    }, {
                                        x: 110,
                                        y: 120
                                    }]    
                            },
                                {dataPoints : [{ x: 0,
                                            y: 0
                                        }, {
                                            x: 5,
                                            y: 40
                                        }, {
                                            x: 15,
                                            y: 70
                                        }, {
                                            x: 25,
                                            y: 90
                                        }, {
                                            x: 36,
                                            y: 110
                                        }, {
                                            x: 55,
                                            y: 125
                                        }, {
                                            x: 68,
                                            y: 135
                                        }, {
                                            x: 75,
                                            y: 100
                                        }, {
                                            x: 120,
                                            y: 30
                                        }]    
                                }];
```

And the function for drawing the line is:

```
        function drawCurveLine(paper, dataline, series, name){

           for(var i=0; i<dataline.length; i++){


            var x1 = dataline[i].dataPoints[i].x * paper.scaleX,
                y1 = dataline[i].dataPoints[i].y * paper.scaleY;


            var s = "M" + x1 + "," + y1;

            for(var j=0; j<dataline[i].dataPoints.length;j++){

               var x2 = dataline[i].dataPoints[j].x * paper.scaleX,
                   y2 = dataline[i].dataPoints[j].y * paper.scaleY;
                   s += " L" + x2 + "," + y2;
            }

            paper.path(s).attr({stroke: "000", "stroke-width": 3});
         }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just construct the complete string and call paper.path once.

```
var s = "M" + x1 + "," + x2;
for(var i=2;i<pts.length-1;i+=2){
  s += " L" + x2 + "," + y2;
}
paper.path(s);
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I tried it out but it gives the error Object #<Object> has no method 'path'.

Comment: Maybe you've created a variable called paper which is hiding the raphael paper object. Guessing though as the issue is likely in code you've not posted.

Comment: The issue has been resolved, thank you for your help!